# MVC & jQuery DatePicker - Remove Date Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm struggling with some DatePicker voodoo and I can't seem to crack it.

Given a model with a date field like:

```
[Display(Name = "MyDate", Description = "Please provide your date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to specify your date")]
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "")]
public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

I then have this is my editor template:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    @Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("d") : string.Empty), new { @class = "datefield date-editor", type = "date" })
}
```

The Date Pickers are setup with the following jQuery:

```
    $('.date-editor').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: '-100:+0',
        defaultDate: '',
        autoSize: true
    });
```

How do I prevent the textbox from containing the pattern?  The date field in the UI contains the following string:

```
dd/mm/yyy
```

Comment: Take the `type = "date"` attribute out. jQuery UI will manage without it.

Comment: Slaps forehead ... that does indeed work.

Comment: Ha! It was just a lucky guess. Since not all browsers currently support the HTML5 "date" input, I thought the best explanation was that your browser had some "unresolved conflicts" with jQuery UI.

Comment: You jammy tyke!  FF 33 here, there is another more elaborate workaround here: http://www.kestrelblackmore.com/blog/jquery-datepicker-mvc4

Comment: Yes, playing with the validator can have it's advantages. I (almost) always end up setting `readonly` on the input and working with strings; then I move all the validation on the server. On the client, the date is controlled by the widget and maintains the desired format. Please note that the example from your link also sets the type of the input to _text_.